# how to preserve haproxy acl value during susequent rules?

Tags: acl, haproxy

haproxy version is 2.5.8

I need send `/v1/main` requests to the alternative backend, but transform path to the `/main` whatever backend used.

Tried:

```
frontend main.dev
  mode http
  acl alternate_path path_beg /v1/main
  http-request set-path /main if { path_end /main }
  ...
  use_backend alt.dev if alternate_path
  ...
```

do not work.

It may be tested with the prints to the logs:

```
frontend main.dev
  mode http
  acl alternate_path path_beg /v1/main
  http-request set-var(txn.acl_trigger) str("placeholder")
  http-request set-path /main if { path_end /main }
  http-request set-var(txn.acl_trigger) str("alt_path") if alternate_path
  ...
  use_backend alt.dev if alternate_path
  ...
  log-format ".... ACL-Triggered:%{+E}[var(txn.acl_trigger)] "
```

grep log shows `... HTTP/1.1" ACL-Triggered:placeholder`

May be I miss this part inside Haproxy documentation. Looks like `acl` don't set the value for its name, but define the evaluation and set it each time it calls.

How protect acl value from the subsequent changes?